# How to add an image inside other image using canvas in Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-bitmap, ontouchlistener

i'm trying to add an image inside other using canvas where the touch event gets fired. The Blueprint is inside of a DialogFragment and loaded by a canvas, the code i have works but the coordinates are wrong and i don't know why.

Loading the blueprint inside canvas:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this
            .getResources(), R.mipmap.blueprint_test);
    bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    //canvas.drawARGB(0x00, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    BitmapDrawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmOverlay);
    dr.setBounds(0, 0, dr.getBounds().width(), dr.getBounds().height());
    blueprint.setImageDrawable(dr);
    blueprint.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Touch Listener

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    int touchX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
    int touchY = (int) motionEvent.getY();
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d(TAG,"Touch coordinates : " +
                    touchX + "x" + touchY);
            canvas.drawBitmap(getMarkerBitmap(),touchX,touchY,null);
            BitmapDrawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmOverlay);
            dr.setBounds(0, 0, dr.getIntrinsicWidth(), dr.getIntrinsicHeight());
            blueprint.setImageDrawable(dr);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is the result:
[image]

The green mark is where the touch event gets fired and the marker appears in other place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it suming the same coordinate from motionEvent.getX() and motionEvent.getY() to the canvas.drawBitmap function and minus the height and width of marker. Also when using the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP to set the bitmap resolves the scroll problem too. Here is the final code of touch listener:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    int touchX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
    int touchY = (int) motionEvent.getY();
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBluePrint, 0, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(getMarkerBitmap(),touchX+touchX,touchY+touchY-120,null);
            blueprint.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I had try it in different size of devices and it works great.